# React-Native-Navigation (v2) Bottom Tab onPress

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I have a Bottom Tab with a Play Button in the middle, I would like to fire a function instead of load a registered screen.

Right now I have:

```
children: [
    {
      component: {
        id: 'player' 
        name: 'navigation.PlayerScreen',
        passProps: {
          text: 'Player',
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

I´m searching if there´s something like that without the need of a screen:

```
children: [
    {
      component: {
        id: 'player'
        onPress: () => playMusic()
      }
    }
  ],
```

Versions:

- "react-native": "0.59.3",
- "react-native-navigation": "2.16.0"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this page... react native provide lots of event/hooks... https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/events

Comment: @sathishkumar I was able to trigger a function with the event `registerBottomTabSelectedListener` but I´m still attached to a screen navigation when I press the button. I just want the function, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

You can do it like this;

1. Create a component called PlayMusic
2. Connect onPress to PlayMusic component
3. Define the PlayMusic component to wix's and then define component.name.

If you want to send parameters to the function, you can use **passProps**. *(Remember to update the PlayMusic component)*

Comment: That´s right, is not possible. Thank you for the alternative, I like the Wix Navigation but we moved to React Navigation and now works like a charm.

Comment: Can you share what's exactly you do in faced same things with react-navigation @NEOline